Angular 16 RxJs Issue Updating Total on Header Component
Hello I have an question regarding my Observable.
I have a cart as well as checkout that works fine when I add a another items to cart
it handles total items as well as total cost. These components are siblings within the shopping-cart folder hierarchy , I mention this because I'm not sure if this is the reason I only get correct total after reload. I have a image next to the shopping cart which is not updating the total items when I add to cart only when I reload.
Like so: 
This is located in the header component which is in a totally different the folder called UI in the hierarchy.  The things I have tried thus far isn't solving my issue, I'm close but not on the money. Understanding this will help me figure out other updates in the header component  such has as user login name with out doing a reload.  Pointing me in the right direction with the subscribe would be greatly appreciated. Code snippet for header component included:
header.component.ts
   Component({
     providers:[NgbModal, NgbModalConfig, ProductItemComponent, ProductListComponent, 
     CartItemComponent, EventEmitter, CartComponent, WishlistListComponent], 
     //NgbModal is a service for mpodal dialog
     selector: 'app-header',
     templateUrl: './header.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
  })

     constructor( private msg: MessengerService, private 
     cartService:CartService,private accountService: AccountService, private 
     modalService: NgbModal, private config: NgbModalConfig,
     private searchService:SearchService, private auth:AuthService, public 
     prodcomp:ProductItemComponent,
     private _imageService:ImageService, private formBuilder: 
     UntypedFormBuilder,private alertService: AlertService,  private _ 
     wishlistitemService: WishlistItemService)

   {

   //Tried to do something like this with no luck      
    // this.cartService.itemTotals$.subscribe((v: any) => (this.itemTotal$ = v));
        
   }

     ngOnInit(): void {
       this.loadCartItems();
    }


     loadCartItems(){
      this.cartService.getCartItems().subscribe((item) => {
      this.cartitems$ = item;
      // alert("A cart item" + item);
      this.calNumberOfItems();
     })
   }



   calNumberOfItems(){;
     for(this.qty=0; this.qty < this.cartitems$.length; this.qty++){
      this.qty
   }
      this.itemTotal$ = this.qty; 

  }

header.html

 </span><span ><i class="fas fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 25px; 
 margin-top: -20px; cursor:none; color:#1D004F;"><strong style="color:#ffffff; margin- 
 left: -18px; padding-top: 0; font-size:10px; text-align: center; line-height: 20px;"> 
 {{itemTotal$}}</strong></i></span></a>            

cart.service.ts
  export interface Cartitems{
  _id: string,
  name: string,
  size: string,
  qty: number,
  price: number,
  imageUrl:string
}



  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'

 })

export class CartService {

  
 rootUrl = 'api';    

 cartitems$= new BehaviorSubject<Cartitems[]>([]);   //this works
  //itemTotals$  = new BehaviorSubject<Cartitems[]>([]);



  getCartItems(): Observable<Cartitems[]> {
   return this.http.get<Cartitems[]>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts/cartitems')
    
  }

}

I only added relevant code if someone could explain to me what I'm
missing I would greatly appreciated
Thanking you advance

I want to thank Tomescu for explaining to me about shared services, although this didn't work for me but it doesn't mean it won't work for some one else.  I was to invested in the way my code was structured to make all the nectary changes that was needed. I do wanted to share this. there is a way to refresh my totals from the header where that icon resides.  It is called Reactive Angular with RXJs auto refresh using a subject. Rather than update my code I would rather share video link, as I stated everyone's code is different.
This forum is to help developers, I know I have been pointed(helped) in the right direction a number of times.  I hope this linked helps many.
Link: enter link description here

You need a service to share data between components like this:


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Cartitems } from './cartitems.interface'; // Ensure you have this interface defined properly

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private cartItemsSource = new BehaviorSubject<Cartitems[]>([]);
  currentCartItems = this.cartItemsSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updateCartItems(cartItems: Cartitems[]) {
    this.cartItemsSource.next(cartItems);
  }
}



For best practices, the services that share data between components should be separate from services that do API requests to get data from db
This would be the service that does the requests to get saved items from db


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Cartitems } from './cartitems.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dataService: DataService) { }

  getCartItems() {
    this.http.get<Cartitems[]>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts/cartitems').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataService.updateCartItems(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Error fetching cart items', error);
      }
    );
  }
}



The service that gets data from db cand depend on your service that shares data, so that once you request data from db you can publish it on the sharedata service
This would be the component that requests the carts from the backend. This is like the main page, where you need to get your products, or can even be cart component. Any place you need to get the cart items that is different from the header component. If in this component you have items that you want to add to your cart, once you add them, you can use the dataService to publish the updated cart items, so that your header can update too


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CartService } from './cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cartService: CartService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cartService.getCartItems();
  }
}



This is how you subscribe to Dataservice in your headerComponent to get shared data between components. Once another component in your angular application updates the dataService, any subscribers will also get notified


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Cartitems } from './cartitems.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  cartItems: Cartitems[] = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.currentCartItems.subscribe(
      cartItems => {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Error getting cart items', error);
      }
    );
  }
}




Hello thanks for your response I worked on the shared service for days.  It just did not work for me.  It also broke some thing in my header.  Most of the research I did with shared service there seems to be a button click involved.  I just want the image to update when when item added to cart .  My cart works fine, I just thought  it would be a great user experience to show  how many items were in cart instead of navigating to cart.
